# Ubuntu 20.04 - Install a specific version of openjdk "1.8.0_201"

Tags: 20.04, java

I have openjdk version "1.8.0_292" installed on my Ubuntu 20.04.

I need to install an exact version of openjdk - 1.8.0_201

How do I do that?

The reason being that an old application I am trying to run is giving me an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version
> number may be negative or greater than 255    at
> com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:154)
> at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:71)

I have 'icu4j_2_6_1.jar' in my lib folder. Upgrading it is causing more errors

Comment: Why do you think you need a specific sub-sub-version?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download

Download the SDK you need in the [Java 8 Archive](https://www.oracle.com/br/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html).

2. Installing

Install it according to [these instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.html).

3. Setting alternative

Include this specific version as an alternative, using this command on your terminal (root needed):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdkXXX/bin/java 1
```

Being:

- `/usr/bin/java` is the result of `which java`;
- `jdkXXX` is the name of the JDK folder you created before.

Finally, set the version you want to use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Select the version you want, typing the number displayed on the first column.

You may need to repeat step 3 with `javac`, `javaws`, etc., according to your needs.

Also, make sure to test the changes with `java -version`.